# Excel logic to find when a cell is not "five-in-a-row" within a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic, formula

I am trying to write some Excel logic which will do the following.

Cells A2:A6 should be the same.
Cells A6:A11 should be the same.
etc. etc.

This continues downwards, five cells in column A should equal one another.

So I have tried :

```
=IF(AND(A2=A3,A2=A4,A2=A5,A2=A6,A3=A4,A3=A5,A3=A6,A4=A5,A5=A6), "True","False")
```

and copied this down through the doc, to give me a column which tells me if there exists a cell which is present any more or less than five times.

The problem is, it increments in ones, rather than fives. So I get true, false, false, false, true, false, false.... instead of a reliable indicator.

How can I write this correctly?

eg

I would like :

```
cell A
1 True
1 True
1 True
1 True
1 True
2 False
3 True
3 True
3 True
3 True
3 True
4 False
4 False
4 False
4 False
...
```

Comment: are you sure it is **A2:A6 and A6:A11**? shouldn't it be **A2:A6 and A7:A11"? i think it is a mistake in the question.

Comment: i think @AHC asked a valid question because it changes whole structure of the formula. Is your set of data grouped in 5's or last cell of the first 5 is common with first cell of the next 5?

Comment: And I have another concern, for example for the last number 3 in your data set, why it is true? Why you are considering it in the group of other number 3s, normally it should be in the set of 4's.

Answer (score 0):

In your first row:

```
=AND(A1=A2,A2=A3,A3=A4,A4=A5)
```

and in your second row and down:

```
=OR(IF(AND(A2=A3,A3=A4,A4=A5,A5=A6),"TRUE","FALSE"),AND(B1,A1=A2))
```

Comment: @THM8885 Thank you for this, and how can I copy paste it to the rest of the document easily?

Comment: How do you mean?  Are you copying into other columns, all the way down column B, etc.?

Comment: @THM8885 Yes, that is the issue. For cells A1:A5 I can use your formula, I need to copy paste the formula until A3000, testing A1:A5, A5:A10, A10:A15, etc

Comment: This formula will continually check to see if there are five cells in a row with the same value.  It will get exactly the same results as your example.

Answer (score 0):

As your dataset isn't organized evenly (groups start only at 1st or 5th rows it would be really difficult (if possible) write a formula using only comparisons as you've tried. My solution always look only forward and instead of comparing backward (e.g. 2nd element of a group) it just check whether previous row belongs to a group of fives and if yes whether actual row has the same value in the first column as previous one.

`=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A6,A2)=5,"True",IF(AND(C1="True",A2=A1),"True","False"))`

This formula will give "True" for all values occuring AT LEAST five times in a group, if you want to get "True" only for exactly five occurrence and "false" for more then five in a group than the formula will be even more complicated.

Of course it's possible to autofill the fromula in your column.